# Twitter calls fail in php but succed in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I've made a website in which I getting my last tweets win two ways. One by using a jQuery plugin and two by php.

The jQuery plugin is http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/ 
The problem I'm facing is the error that php gives me.

If I use file_get_contents($url) without a context it gives me

> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request

If I use file_get_contents with a context of "ignore_errors"=>true, it gives me

> array(2) { ["request"]=> string(61) "/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=xxxxxx&count=1" ["error"]=> string(74) "Rate limit exceeded. Clients may not make more than 150 requests per hour." }

The strange thing, and the reason I'm asking this question is that the jQuery plugin always succeds.

If I console.log the request from the plugin, is the same with the url I'm trying to get via php:

> http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=xxxxxxxx&count=1&include_rts=1&page=1&include_entities=1

Does anyone can tell me what happens?

Comment: Rate limit exceeded. Clients may not make more than 150 requests per hour. - Do you did this request from server? I think twitter counts request from one IP address. If your do it in jquery - your local machine do this request. Try to do jquery request more than 150 requests - and you got this error too.

Comment: Ah yes! I totaly forgot that difference. I think that this question falls under the "stupid" category. Thank you!